# Can we access twitter updates in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

Please help me out the following scenario.
1.can we access the twitter update messages in windows phone 7?

please clarify me hoe to  achieve?.Any API for that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need a Twitter library for .NET. [There are **plenty**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet). Choose the one that fits your needs.